# GWT unable to retrieve result from servlet

Tags: java, gwt, instance

I am currently developing a GUI (with GWT) for something similar to a sorting framework and up to the last step everything works just fine. But I am unable to retrieve the data due to a `JavaScriptException`:

```
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : this$static[signature][0] is not a function
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.$instantiate(0.js@35:10985)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.instantiate_13(0.js@12:10952)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.deserialize_18(0.js@30:10259)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.readObject(0.js@15:10126)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.deserialize_7(0.js@24:9909)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.deserialize_5(0.js@3:9875)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.$deserialize(0.js@28:10977)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.deserialize_19(0.js@5:10936)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.deserialize_18(0.js@19:10261)
Tue May 29 09:46:56 GMT+200 2018 debug SEVERE: Unknown.readObject(0.js@15:10126)
```

To be honest I am absolutely clueless about javascript so I just assumed something went wrong when the returning object was instantiated but in this case I am using `java.util.Map<String,java.util.List<?>>` and made sure that I really use those from the `java.util` package.

The responsible code looks as follows:

**SortingFramework.java (Interface):**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath ( "framework")
public interface SortingFramework<T extends Comparable<T>>
    extends RemoteService
{
  public Map<String,List<?>> getResults();
}
```

**SortingFrameworkAsync.java (Interface):**

```
public interface SortingFrameworkAsync<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
  void getResults( AsyncCallback<Map<String, List<?>>> result ) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**SortingFrameworkImpl.java (Servlet):**

```
public class SortingFrameworkImpl<E extends Comparable<E>>
    extends RemoteServiceServlet
    implements SortingFramework<E>
{
 Map<String,List<?>> results = new HashMap<String,List<?>>();     

  @Override
  public Map<String, List<?>> getResults()
  {
    boolean b;
    do
    {
         // will return true when everything is done.
         b = !isDone();
     }
     while ( b );

    return new HashMap<String,List<?>>(results); // also tried to simply return results here
  }
}
```

In this case I omitted how `results` is populated since it's not part of the problem and I made sure that no values are `null` or from a different type. In short: The map is exactly as I want it.

Now the calling part:

**ResultPresenterImpl.java (Presenter for a ResultView):**

```
public class ResultPresenterImpl
    implements ResultPresenter
{
// gets set at an earlier point than the error occurs
private SortingFrameworkAsync<?> model;

  @Override
  public void initView()
  {
    model.getResults( new AsyncCallback<Map<String,List<?>>>()
    {
      // here the exception gets caught.
      @Override
      public void onFailure( Throwable caught )
      {
        log.severe( caught.toString() );
        for(StackTraceElement element : caught.getStackTrace())
        {
          log.severe( element.toString() );
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess( Map<String, List<?>> result )
      {
        addContentToView( result );
      }
    } );
    view.show();
  }
}
```

The `initView()` method will only be called when the user confirmed everything neccessary and the remote call procedure should wait for `getResult()` actually returning something but somehow it fails with the exception mentioned above.

I made sure that everything has a vallue and `null` does not occure at any point. So my question is: How can the remote procedure call fail? What is the cause of the exception?

At first I thought that GWT might not be able to serialize/desieralize a `Map<String,List<?>>` but I tried that in an empty project and it worked out just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At first I thought that GWT might not be able to serialize/desieralize a `Map<String,List<?>>` but I tried that in an empty project and it worked out just fine.

Your instinct here is correct - GWT can't tell what `?` means, so doesn't prepare any types for serialization, but chances are you are sending some object in that list and it doesn't know how to send it.

> `this$static[signature][0] is not a function`

The value of `signature` is the name of the class that was serialized by the server, but can't be read by the client. The fact that is says "is not a function" likely means that gwt thinks your data *is* serializable, but might think it can only be sent in a different direction - the `[0]` is trying to read a function out of a a set of three functions - one to instantiate a serialized value, one to finish deserializing fields, and one to serialize fields to send to the server.